# Sorting a List of Mixed Data?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, sorting, collections

I had an interview today and in that i was asked to sort an list which contains String and Integers.it was like this

Input:

car bus 4 -5 apple 3 -1

Output:

apple bus -5 -1 car 3 4

I was stuck at first as i never saw anything like that but what i tried to do is that to create 2 sub-list,One which holds strings and other one which holds int.I did this but time was already up and i couldnt finish.

Also i got stuck at the part where i tried to loop through list and check if its string than add elements to sublist 1 and if its int than add the element to sublist 2.I got stuck here bcoz i didnt know how can i check if element is String or Int.

Also sorry if i have posted this question in wrong section or something.Feel free to move this question to the right section.

Thank You

Comment: Re: checking if string or int: try parsing it? What's "higher", a number, or a string? How's the input coming, all as strings?

Comment: The first thing I would point out to the interviewer is that `-1` is a string, too... then I would discuss ways to tell the difference (probably try to parse it and `try/catch (NumberFormatException e)`...)

Comment: @DaveNewton parsing is exactly what came to my mind.He showed me the output as the one i have wrote above i think he wanted me to give priority to words over numbers while sorting.He didnt say anything about how input was coming.He said its the combination of string and integers.Thanks for the response.

Comment: @durron597 parsing came to my mind but i think i lost it as the time was about to end and i was under pressure :) Also i think trying to parse every element every time will take lot of time so is there any other way or no? thanks for the response.

Comment: Why is `-1 -5`? It should be `-5 -1` in the output

Comment: @Cratylus sorry it was a mistake.i have corrected it.thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So are you sorting a `List<Object>`? Or just the string `"car bus 4 -5 apple 3 -1"`?

Comment: @A.R.S. i was told that list is combination of int and strings so i guess its was of Objects and not the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use two lists, sort them, but you have to remember the original ordering, a `LinkedList<Boolean>` is sufficient for that task.

```
public static String sortString(String input) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

    LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<Integer> integers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Boolean> types = new LinkedList<Boolean>();

    while(s.hasNext()) {
        String nextToken = s.next();
        try {
            int nextInteger = Integer.parseInt(nextToken);
            integers.add(nextInteger);
            types.add(true);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            strings.add(nextToken);
            types.add(false);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(strings);
    Collections.sort(integers);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    Iterator<Boolean> iter = types.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        boolean currType = iter.next();
        if (currType) {
            builder.append(integers.remove(0));
        } else {
            builder.append(strings.remove(0));
        }
        if (iter.hasNext()) builder.append(" ");
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `-1` and `-5` are `int` a simple solution:

```
public String sortStringWithInts(String input){  
        String[] parts = input.split("\\s");  
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();  
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
        for(String part:parts){  
            if(isNumber(part)){                 
                 ints.add(Integer.valueOf(part));               
            }  
            else{  
                strings.add(part);  
            }  
        }  
        Collections.sort(strings);  
        Collections.sort(ints);  
        return createResult(strings, ints, parts);           
    }  

    private String createResult(List<String> strings, List<Integer> ints, String[] parts) {  
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();       
        for(String part:parts){  
            if(isNumber(part)){  
                result.append(ints.remove(0)).append(" ");              
            }  
            else{  
                result.append(strings.remove(0)).append(" ");  
            }  
        }  

        return result.toString();  
    }  

    private boolean isNumber(String part) {  
        try{  
            Integer.valueOf(part);  
            return true;  
        }  
        catch(Exception e){  
            return false;  
        }  
    }
```

**Note:** the output would be: `apple bus -5 -1 car 3 4` since `-5 < -1` and not like in your OP